# Data shifting columns after aggregation [Hive]

Tags: sql, hive

I am aggregating table in Hive. After aggregation, some of the data is shifting from left to right, and maybe the other way as well, not sure yet.

Sample data below.

```
+---------+------------+------+
|  Site   |    Date    | Sent |
+---------+------------+------+
| Twitter | 2019-01-01 | pos  |
| Twitter | 2019-01-01 | pos  |
| Twitter | 2019-01-01 | neg  |
| Twitter | 2019-01-01 | pos  |
+---------+------------+------+
```

The code is simple. 
1. separate the various sentiment options
2. Count and group by the site and date

```
  SELECT site, date
       , COUNT(CASE sent WHEN 'negative'THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS negative_
       , COUNT(CASE sent WHEN 'positive' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS positive_
    FROM my_table
GROUP BY date, site;
```

Expected result

```
+---------+------------+------+-----------+-----------+
|  Site   |    Date    | Sent | negative_ | positive_ |
+---------+------------+------+-----------+-----------+
| Twitter | 2019-01-01 | pos  | 0         |         3 |
| Twitter | 2019-01-01 | neg  |         1 |         0 |
+---------+------------+------+-----------+-----------+
```

Actual result is something like this. Some of the rows are shifting over a column and it seems a couple others are shifting the other direction. This is not a problem I've ever encountered. I have asked internally about the data pipeline and the specified delimiter, if any. No respect yet but I don't know if that could be the cause.

```
+---------+------------+------------+-----------+-----------+
|  Site   |    Date    |    Sent    | negative_ | positive_ |
+---------+------------+------------+-----------+-----------+
| Twitter |  NULL      | 2019-01-01 |         0 |         3 |
| Twitter | 2019-01-01 | neg        |         1 |         0 |
+---------+------------+------------+-----------+-----------+
```

Does anyone have any idea why? What I could do about it?

---

SO wants me to write more for this to be submitted, I don't know what else to write. The above seems fairly straightforward.

Answer (score 0):

Your code would not produce the output that you specify, because `COUNT()` counts non-`NULL` values.  The `ELSE 0` means that the `CASE` expression is always returning a non-`NULL` value, so the two counts should produce the same value in each row.  That is not what the results show.

The code that you intend is:

```
SELECT site, date,
       SUM(CASE sent WHEN 'negative'THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS negative_
       SUM(CASE sent WHEN 'positive' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS positive_
FROM my_table
GROUP BY date, site;
```

This probably won't fix the alignment issue, which may have more to do with the tool you are using than with the results of the query.

Comment: Also I am using Alation